# Gradle: Accept resource files in src/main/java folder

Tags: gradle

Is there a way to convince Gradle to accept resource files (like XML files) as well in the `src/main/java` folder?

This would be great since I need to put my JavaFX XML files there ...

Comment: what's your problem? what doesn't work? is this about deployed resources not being available somewhere? why not use the convention of putting them in src/main/resources? Have you looked at https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/java_plugin.html to see you can redefine where the resources subdir is?

Comment: I can't help you with Gradle but why do you need to put your FXML? files there?

Comment: @mipa JavaFX Scene Builder expects the FXML files in the same folder as the Controller class.

Comment: @Mark_Fisher I cannot due to the fact JavaFX Scene Builder expects the FXML there.

Comment: I think it'd be helpful if you could describe how Gradle isn't working for you

Comment: @EricWendelin I put an XML file (for JavaFX) in folder /src/main/java and it is not part of the build. If I put it in /src/main/resources it is part of the build. Due to the fact how JavaFX Secne Builder works the FXML files need to be in the same folder as the Java sources, and that's why I cannot put the file in the resources folder.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could define where gradle looks for resource files by doing something like this:

```
sourceSets {
    main {
        resources {
            srcDirs = ["src/main/java"]
            includes = ["**/*.fxml"]
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Well this actually did the trick. But is this a good/nice solution for the problem?

Comment: This is exactly in line with Gradle best practices, so I'd vote "yes"

Comment: If you are going to use this approach of allowing resources in `src/main/java` (which I personally hate) I'd suggest you use `excludes = ["**/*.java"]` instead of `includes = ["**/*.fxml"]`

Comment: Definitely NOT Gradle best practices!!!!! You should use the very sensible convention of `src/main/resources`

Comment: @LanceJava So who is wrong: Gradle who expects resources in `src/main/resources` or Oracle who expects FXML files in the same folder als the Controller classes?

Comment: If you put `fxml` files in `src/main/resources` tthey WILL be in the same folder as the `.class` files. They just won't be in the same folder as the `.java` files. Surely Oracle should care about the runtime classpath and NOT the locations of your source files?

Comment: And in answer to your question. Gradle can adapt to this poor setup if required. It's just not the default convention... because it's silly. So it's oracle who is "wrong" in my opinion... because it's a silly default which can't be changed. The folder is `src/main/java` because it contains `java` files.

Answer (score 0):

The equivalent Kotlin DSL would be:

```kotlin
sourceSets {
    main {
        resources {
            srcDirs("src/main/java")
            include("**/*.fxml")
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

As the name suggests `src/main/java` is for JAVA files. Whilst it's possible to tweak gradle's defaults to allow resources in this folder, you shouldn't (in my opinionated view).

I suggest you stick to the sensible conventions and put your xml etc in `src/main/resources`. This convention is followed by both Maven and Gradle.

Comment: OP states that they are using javaFX which (apparently) forces then to place the fxml files in the same path as their Java files. It didn't seem to be their *choice* to violate convention. Gradle supports customizing location of resources exactly for this type of situation, is it not?

Comment: Sure... if it MUST be this way then Gradle will let you do this as shown in the other answer. Never used javaFX myself but surprised that it forces this convention.

Comment: I know how answer reflects how people used to think back in the day, but there's nothing sensible about requiring us to separate files into directories by their type. This convention is ridiculous. Instead, files should be grouped logically, by the their joint purpose.